# Cannot click iAd Banner added to Phonegap app with slight offset

Tags: ios, cordova, iad

So I roughly followed [this](http://hawkinbj.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/implement-iad-banner-ads-without-covering-uiwebview-in-phonegap/) tutorial on how to make an iAd banner not cover a Phonegap app, but had to improvise because it didn't really work.  So in my `webViewDidFinishLoad`  in my `mainViewController` method, here is what I have:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 70);    
    adView.delegate = self;
    [adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    [theWebView addSubview:adView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:adView];
    return [ super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView ];
}
```

`adView` has been properly initialized and is functioning properly.  What breaks this (as in I can't click the banner) is this code in `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {
        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 70;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
    }

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

I added the 70px offset in order to have the banner not cover the content.  Now, if I remove this code, I can click the banner fine.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.  I was adding the subview to `theWebView` instead of `self.view`, which made it outside of its boundary and unclickable.